# Statistical Analysis 1: What is the probablity that this sample proportion is less than the population proportion by 0.06 or more?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have not gotten this wording before in regards to this question:

"Mong Corporation makes auto batteries. The company claims that 80% of its LL70 batteries are good for 70 months or longer. Assume that this claim is true. Let $\hat{p}$ be the proportion in a sample of 100 such batteries that are good for 70 months or longer."

Now I cannot figure out whether it is asking:

1. $p(\hat{p} < 0.06)$
2. $p(\hat{p} < .80 - 0.06) = p(\hat{p} < .74)$

Comment: I think you left off part of the question (something referring to 0.06). Sounds like you should use the binomial distribution for this one!